# Displaying all the files in a folder using win32 C++

Tags: c++, file, winapi, find, messagebox

I have a folder with about 9 files in it and I am trying to get my code to display Messageboxes for each file in the folder with the name of the file, when a button is pressed. For some reason, it only displays a messagebox for the very last file in the folder and then gives me the error: "Error finding files." which is from the error handler I created if (fileError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES). I am not sure why it is not displaying all the file names and giving me an error. The relevant part of my code is below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

TCHAR file_buff[200];
TCHAR file_buff2[200];
TCHAR file_buff3[200];
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
DWORD fileError_initial = 0;
DWORD fileError = 0;
```

In the button press that should give me all the messageboxes:

```
case IDC_BUTTON_RUN:

    hFind = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\Users\\sallen\\Desktop\\Folder1\\*", &FindFileData);

    fileError_initial = GetLastError();

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wsprintfW(file_buff, L"No files were found.\n Error: %s.", fileError_initial);
        MessageBox(NULL, file_buff, L"File Search Error", 0);
        return fileError_initial;
    }

    else
    {
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);
        {
            wsprintf(file_buff2, L"The first file found is %s.\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
            MessageBox(hWnd, file_buff2, L"File Name", 0);
        }

        fileError = GetLastError();
        if (fileError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            wsprintfW(file_buff3, L"Error finding files. %s", fileError);
            MessageBox(hWnd, file_buff3, L"File Search Error", 0);
        }

    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return fileError;

    break;
```

Comment: 1. What’s the point of `else`? 2. `FindFirstFile` returns the first file. You ignore it. 3. There is an example on MS Docs site.

Comment: First of all, you'll not see a message box about the first file you find because you're calling `FindNextFile` before printing information about the first file. Secondly, how do you know you're only seeing the last of the files in the directory? `FindFIrstFIle`/`FindNextFIle` do not necessarily return files in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm wanting it to loop through all the files until there aren't any more to loop through. Won't the while loop do that since I'm doing "while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);"? When I print out the file name after calling FindFirstFile, it gives me "." I've looked at the example on the MS Docs site.

Comment: I did it just like the example at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory but for some reason it does not work for me

Comment: I've updated it to use a do-while loop and this works and gets all the files in order, however it also finds files "." and ".." before the actual files in the folder. Why does it do this when I don't have any files with names "." and ".."?

Comment: @Sophia "*I did it just like the example*" - no, you are not, actually.  There are some significant differences between your code and the example code. Look at it again more carefully.

Comment: @Sophia "*it also finds files "." and ".." before the actual files in the folder*" - as it should be. "*Why does it do this when I don't have any files with names "." and ".."?*" - you don't any such files of your own, but the filesystem does. `"."` represents the *current folder*, and `".."` represents the *parent folder*. You have to ignore them manually if you don't want to process them.

Comment: @Sophia "*I've updated it to use a do-while loop*" - for future reference, please do not edit your questions in a manner that invalidates posted answers. I have reverted your edit this time. If you want to make edits, that's fine, but they should be used add new information or correct mistakes, not to alter the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` statement has an erroneous `;` on it:

```cpp
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0); // <-- here
```

Thus, you loop without processing `FindFileData` until `FindNextFile()` fails, AND THEN you process the last `FindFileData` data that was reported.  And that display ends up wiping out the error code that the failed `FindNextFile()` reported, which is why the error code is no longer `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES` when you actually retrieve it.

You need to remove that erroneous `;`.

Also, you should use a `do..while` loop instead.  Using a `while` loop will skip the 1st file that `FindFirstFile()` reports.

Try this instead:

```cpp
case IDC_BUTTON_RUN:

    hFind = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\Users\\sallen\\Desktop\\Folder1\\*", &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fileError = GetLastError();
        if (fileError == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            fileError = 0;
            MessageBox(NULL, L"No files were found.", L"File Search Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        }
        else
        {
            wsprintfW(file_buff, L"Error finding files. %d", fileError);
            MessageBox(hWnd, file_buff, L"File Search Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        return fileError;
    }

    do
    {
        if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
        {      
            MessageBox(hWnd, FindFileData.cFileName, L"File Name", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

    fileError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (fileError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        wsprintfW(file_buff, L"Error finding files: %d", fileError);
        MessageBox(hWnd, file_buff, L"File Search Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
        fileError = 0;

    return fileError;
```

---

**UPDATE**: to handle sub-folders, you will have to move your code into a recursive function, eg:

```cpp
DWORD SearchFolder(LPCTSTR folder)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    TCHAR mask[MAX_PATH+3], filePath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwError, dwResult;

    PathCombine(mask, folder, L"*");

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(mask, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return GetLastError();

    dwResult = ERROR_NO_FILES_FOUND;

    do
    {
        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (lstrcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, ".") == 0 || lstrcmp(FindFileData.cFileName, "..") == 0)
                continue;

            PathCombine(filePath, folder, FindFileData.cFileName);           
            dwError = SearchFolder(filePath);

            if (dwError != NO_ERROR && dwError != ERROR_NO_FILES_FOUND) {
                SetLastError(dwError);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {      
            // do something with FindFileData.cFileName ...

            PathCombine(filePath, folder, FindFileData);
            ...

            dwResult = NO_ERROR;
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

    dwError = GetLastError();
    FindClose(hFind);

    if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        return dwError;

    return dwResult;
}

...

case IDC_BUTTON_RUN:
{
    DWORD dwResult = SearchFolder(L"C:\\Users\\sallen\\Desktop\\Folder1\\");
    if (dwResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        if (dwResult == ERROR_NO_FILES_FOUND) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"No files were found.", L"File Search Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        }
        else {
            swprintf(file_buff, L"Error finding files. %u", dwError);
            MessageBox(hWnd, file_buff, L"File Search Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }
    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm I have reverted it

Comment: Can FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() also find folders within the directory and folders within folders, along with all files in those folders?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to make those calls recursively. `FindFileData.dwFileAttributes` will have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` attribute set when it finds a matching folder, and `FindFileData.cFileName` will have the folder name. Ignore the `"."` and `".."` folders, and call a new `Find(First|Next)File()` loop for each folder you find.

Comment: In your example above, "(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0", but in order to find folders and files, I did FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) but this is only finding the folders, not the files.

Comment: @Sophia The original example was looking for only files and ignoring folders. See the update I just posted, it searches for both folders and files

Comment: I placed the SearchFolder function at the end of my code but for some reason, within "case IDC_BUTTON_RUN:", it is not recognized. It gives me error: "'SearchFolder': identifier not found. It also says within the function that "'hWnd': undeclared identifier".

Comment: @Sophia obviously, if you move the function to the end of your code, then you will have to declare the function earlier before you can use it. As for the `hWnd` error, that was my mistake. The `MessageBox()` should not have been in my example, I have removed it now. If you want to put it back in, you will have to pass an `HWND` into the function, either as another input parameter, or using a global variable. Or, just set the `hWnd` parameter of `MessageBox()` to NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227009/discussion-between-sophia-and-remy-lebeau).